# Removing control from a dynamic interface

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dynamic

I'm working on a c# exercise project in order to develop my skills and learn new things. i have created a dynamic interface which consists of a few controls.. when the form is loaded it starts up with a numericUpDown and a Button. when the user selects a number on the numeric up down and clicks the button it will generate as many text boxes depending on the number selected on the numericUpDown it also generates a remove button next to the generated text box. i am having trouble to delete the textbox when the user clicks the delete button

this is the code that i have:

// generating textbox and button

```
private void AssessmentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int length = (int)this.NoAssesmentBoxlv4.Value;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    textboxAssesmentName.Add(new TextBox());
    var p = new System.Drawing.Point(110, 260 + i * 25);                     
    (textboxAssesmentName[i] as TextBox).Location = p;
    (textboxAssesmentName[i] as TextBox).Size = new System.Drawing.Size(183, 20);
    this.Lv4Tab.Controls.Add(textboxAssesmentName[i] as TextBox);
    buttoRemove.Add(new Button());
    (buttoRemove[i] as Button).Location = new System.Drawing.Point(380, 260 + i * 25);
    (buttoRemove[i] as Button).Text = @"x";
    (buttoRemove[i] as Button).BackColor = Color.Red;
    (buttoRemove[i] as Button).ForeColor = Color.White;
    (buttoRemove[i] as Button).Size = new System.Drawing.Size(22, 23);
    this.Lv4Tab.Controls.Add(buttoRemove[i] as Button);

    (buttoRemove[i] as Button).Click += this.buttoRemove_click;
  }
}
```

Here is the soruce for the remove button's Click: ( this method does not compile )

```
private void buttoRemove_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (Object obj in textboxAssesmentName)
  {
    // THIS LINE DOES NOT COMPILE!!!
    this.Controls.Remove(textboxAssesmentName.Remove);
  }
}
```

any ideas would be much appreciated

Comment: What does *"does not work"* mean? [We are not mind readers.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/102937)

Comment: does not remove any controls its underlined in red in my code

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
foreach (var control in textboxAssesmentName)
{
    this.Controls.Remove(control);
}
```

Your existing code doesn't make any sense.

**See also** 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82785s1h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the `Tag` property of the `Button` to store the `TextBox` associated with it. To put it in your code, insert this line in your loop:

```
(buttoRemove[i] as Control).Tag = textboxAssesmentName[i];
```

Then your event handler would look like this:

```
private void buttoRemove_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Remove((sender as Control).Tag as Control);
}
```

Edit: Here is the way I would write the code (excluding typos).

```
private void AssessmentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int length = (int)this.NoAssesmentBoxlv4.Value;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        TextBox t = new TextBox();
        System.Drawing.Point p = new System.Drawing.Point(110, 260 + i * 25);                     
        t.Location = p;
        t.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(183, 20);

        Button b = new Button();
        b.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(380, 260 + i * 25);
        b.Text = @"x";
        b.BackColor = Color.Red;
        b.ForeColor = Color.White;
        b.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(22, 23);
        b.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttoRemove_click);

        this.Lv4Tab.Controls.Add(t);
        this.Lv4Tab.Controls.Add(b);
        textboxAssesmentName.Add(t);
        buttoRemove.Add(b);
    }
}

private void buttoRemove_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control b = sender as Control;
    Control t = b.Tag as Control;
    this.Lv4Tab.Controls.Remove(t);
    this.Lv4Tab.Controls.Remove(b);
    textboxAssesmentName.Remove(t);
    buttoRemove.Remove(b);
}
```

Comment: this keeps removing the the remove button only and if i hit the generate button twice it keeps generated copies so id have to hit the remove button twice to remove it